# Android get type of a view

Tags: java, android, gettype

How can i do this?

something:

```
final View view=FLall.getChildAt(i);

if (view.getType()==ImageView) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If, for some strange reason, you can't use **Asahi**'s suggestion (using tags), my proposition would be the following:

```
if (view instanceof ImageView) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
    // do what you want with imageView
}
else if (view instanceof TextView) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    // do what you want with textView
}
else if ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work for ListView. And, I have to create another custom CustomListView which extends ListView, so that I can use (view instanceof CustomListView). Is there any way to know the type when it is ListView? Thanks.

Comment: @mabeiyi if `view instanceof ListView` is `false`, it means your view is not a `ListView`.

Comment: @Felix - actually if you have a ListView and you have set "singleChoice" then it will return a class name of "android.widget.CheckedTextView". This has just bit me. This does this under the covers. :(

Answer (score 32):

I tried the following and it worked:

```
View view = FLall.getChildAt(i);
Log.i("ViewName", view.getClass().getName());
```

For Kotlin, the equivalent code is

```
val view: View = FLall.getChildAt(i);
Log.i("ViewName", view.javaClass.name);
```

Comment: I am using a TextView to set the style for a spinner (link in this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html). I am also utilizing the onItemSelected event method for the spinner. The event kept triggering with a a view that I didn't recognize. Using your method above -- v.getClass().getName() -- I was able to determine that the View being passed into the event is the TextView I'm using for the styles.

Answer (score 10):

For Others who check this Question,in some cases `instanceof` does not work(I do not know why!),for example if your want to check if view type is `ImageView` or `ImageButton`(i tested this situation) , it get them the same, so you scan use this way :

```
//v is your View
    if (v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.ImageView")) {
        Log.e("imgview", v.toString());
        imgview = (ImageView) v;
    } else if (v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.ImageButton")) {
        Log.e("imgbtn", v.toString());
        imgbtn = (ImageButton) v; 
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use tag for that purpose:see set/getTag methods at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution for KOTLIN code, so going off of **Arash's** solution:

```
if(v.javaClass.name.equals("android.widget.ImageView", ignoreCase = true)) ...
```

using this didn't work for me, but tweaking it to:

```
if(v.javaClass.name.contains("ImageView", ignoreCase = true)) ...
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can check this by using "is":

```
val view = findViewById<View>(R.id.a_view)

if (view is ImageView) {
    print("This is a ImageView")
} else {
    print("This is not a ImageView")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Xamarin, This is how Android get type of a view and compare with controller type.

```
var view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emailText);

if (typeof(TextView).IsInstanceOfType(view))
{
    var textView = (TextView)view;
}
```