# How to identify if a view is Button or Textview

Tags: android, view, textview, instanceof

I have a error function that takes `View` as an input, and shows error by changing its background to red while there is any problem with view's value as follows -

```
public static void error(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    }
```

I am using this function in another function where I am using it this way -

```
public static void nonEmptyNonZero(View v) {
    String check = "";
    check = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
    if ((check.equals(null)) || check.equals("0") || check.equals("")) {
        error(v);
    }
}
```

my issue is, that `v` could be anything (TextView, EditText). So how to identify what is the type of the view. So that I could use proper casting while getting its value using -

`check = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();`

PS - I have used `instanceOf` already, I am not sure how casting of a `View` works.

Comment: You could just be sneaky, and cast to button, with a try catch, that would hence be textview (Assuming it is always one or the other) But there are much better ways.

Comment: Shouldn't `instanceOf` work? `*View extends View`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118062/android-get-type-of-a-view

Comment: `v.getClass().getName()` will return type of view in String.

Comment: @kstachniuk I used instanceOf and got it working, I was wondering if I could know a way to get text directly from view without even casting it to something else. Or, some function that I might have not noticed which tells what type of object my view is.

Comment: If you are sure that the view contains text (EditText, Button or TextView) you can just cast this view to TextView because EditText (and Button) are extending TextView. And next you can use getText() method

Answer (score 0):

> Like your Views in Object List

```
List<Object> objectViews=new ArrayList();
```

**views**

```
EditText txtEditText=new EditText();
TextView txtTextView=new TextView();
objectViews.add(txtEditText); 
objectViews.add(txtTextView);
```

**traverse to find object (view)**

```
Object view=new Object();
for(int i=0;i<objectViews.size;i++)
{
   view.get(i);
   if(view instanceof EditText)
    {
      Log.e("EditText","value="((EditText) view).getText());
    }
else if(view instanceof TextView)
    {
      Log.e("TextView","value="((TextView) view).getText());
    }
}
```