# Is there any way to check whether the view is an edit text or not in android?

Tags: android

I am just iterating the views where i want to check whether the iterated  view is an edit text or not?

need help,thanks in advance..

Comment: Simply use instanceof.

Comment: This question is discussed here in below link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118062/android-get-type-of-a-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are objects of different classes.  [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) inherits from [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). So as per normal java code you can just use `instanceof`:

```
if (thisView instanceof EditText) {
   // it is
}
else {
   // it isn't
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chekout this , it would help you

```
public void isViewEditText(LinearLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            //Do your stuff here
        } 
    }

}
```