# Android : How to get view class from a view to use with instanceOf

Tags: java, android, android-view, viewgroup

I'm trying to get a view by type inside a viewgroup by returning the first view found view.

```
private View findViewByType(ViewGroup p, View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.getChildCount(); i++)
        if (p.getChildAt(i) instanceof v.getClass()) 
            return p.getChildAt(i);
}
```

I can't seem to get `view.getClass()` to work. How do I get the class from a view?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118062/android-get-type-of-a-view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be

```
p.getChildAt(i).getClass().isInstance(v)
```

`isIsntance(Object)` determines if the specified `Object` is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this `Class`. You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

Change your if like this:

```
 private View findViewByType(ViewGroup p, View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < p.getChildCount(); i++)
           if (p.getChildAt(i).getClass().isInstance(v))  
return p.getChildAt(i);
    }
```