# How to show create file name with Spinner and EditText view names?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

Update figured it out how to save text from Spinner

```
params.put("name",staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
```

Currently need to figure it out how to connect `staticSpinner.getSelectedItem()` and `mEditText.getText()`

How could I make `Spinner` and `EditText` view names to be shown on a file. Currently I have `EditText` saving option. I would like to have possibility to save `Spinner` and `EditText` string values.
For example right now picture is saved mEditText.jpg

And I would like for it to be like this:

> *Spinner_EditText.jpg*

Saving name from EditText:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name",mEditText.getText().toString().trim());
    params.put("image",ImageToString(bitmap));
    return params;
}
```

Spinner MainActivity.java

```
staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.brew_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
```

Spinner strings:

```
<string-array name="brew_array">
    <item>7ch</item>
    <item>11ch</item>
    <item>12ch</item>
    <item>9ch</item>
    <item>14ch</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: This did not help. Already tried it.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483782/5272951 . But instead of using `getName()` I suggest you to use `getSimpleName()`.

Comment: Did it myself, had to modifie my upload php file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did it myself, had to modify my upload PHP file. name2 is spinner and name1 is edit text field

```
$name =date('Y').date('m').date('d'). "_" . date('H'). date('i'). "_". $_POST["name2"]."_".$_POST["name1"];
```